# Flutter keyboard animation background

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a popup box and once you click it so you can type in it. The background of the keyboard in animation turns gray and it doesn't look nice on the way up.

https://gyazo.com/1fefbbd18647217b2ac70d7adee24c89

This is how it looks before:

https://gyazo.com/27b9d50e213b3e5bd42534def538c36e

And this is how it looks on the way up.

Do you have any ideas why it would do this? (The popup box is just a showDialog)

Comment: Look at widget inspector to check if is there any widget on gray area.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run your app on a real device to see what happens ? Sometimes that could be just an emulator miss display